# Complex Conjugate in the form $x+iy$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this complex number: $$e^{t \sin \phi - i \tan \phi} $$

I want to find its conjugate however I am confused by the form it is currently in. I was thinking of it to be similar to $re^{i\theta}$ , with $r$ being $1$ here, but the $t\sin$ in the exponent is giving me issues. In addition, how would I get the trig functions into $x+iy$? Normally I would have done $re^{i\theta}$ which would then be $r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.

Comment: Please take the time to enter _all_ relevant information to your question as text instead of posting pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen-reading software. You can find a quick reference to using MathJax to format mathematical expressions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've used MathJax to edit your question. Please check if i missed something.

Comment: It would be important to know if the $\phi$ shown in your first expression is a real number (so that $\sin \phi$ and $\tan \phi$ also are real values).

Comment: Think that here $r=e^{t\sin\phi}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\overline{e^z}=e^{\overline z}$$

because

$$\overline{e^z}=e^{x}\overline{(\cos y+i\sin y)}=e^{x}{(\cos\ y-i\sin y)}=e^{\overline z}.$$

---

More generally, if $f$ is an holomorphic function taking real values on the real axis, $\overline{f(z)}=f(\overline z)$.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 for the answer I was going to give.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got 
$$e^{t \sin \phi - i \tan \phi} = \underbrace{e^{-i \tan \phi}}_{\text{complex}}\underbrace{e^{t \sin \phi}}_{\text{real}}$$
So the complex conjugate here would be 
\begin{equation}
 e^{i \tan \phi} e^{t \sin \phi}
\end{equation}
i.e. where we have used $y^* = \alpha^* z^* = \alpha z^*$ since $\alpha$ is real. and the conjugate of $z = e^{i \tan \phi}$ is $z^* = e^{-i \tan \phi}$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$e^{t\sin \phi-i\tan \phi}=e^{t\sin \phi}\cdot e^{-i\tan \phi}$$

and therefore

$$\overline{e^{t\sin \phi-i\tan \phi}}=\overline{e^{t\sin \phi}\cdot e^{-i\tan \phi}}=e^{t\sin \phi}\cdot \overline{e^{-i\tan \phi}}=e^{t\sin \phi}\cdot e^{i\tan \phi}=e^{t\sin \phi+i\tan \phi}$$

indeed

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta \implies \overline{e^{i\theta}}=\overline{\cos \theta+i\sin \theta}=\cos \theta-i\sin \theta=e^{-i\theta}$$

Comment: so would theta be the tan portion? @gimusi

Comment: @Jytrex In the last line $\theta$ is a generic real value which represent the argument of the complex number and it correspond to $\tan \phi$ in your expression.